# RxJs: How to invoke method when work in subscriptions of two observables is done

Tags: rxjs

I'm loading data from different API endpoints and then do some synchronous work on each data set:

```
// Invoked by user interaction
loadData() {
    this.service1.getData().subscribe(
      data => {
        this.doSynchronousWork(data);
        this.data1 = data;
      }
    );

    this.service2.getData().subscribe(
      data => {
        this.doSynchronousWork(data);
        this.data2 = data;
      }
    );
}

// To be invoked when this.data1 and this.data2 is available
doSynchronousWorkWhenAllDataIsLoadedAndProcessed()
```

Now I need to invoke another synchronous method when both subscribtions have done their work. How can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To achieve this, you use `forkJoin`, where you add up all your observables as an array and they run asynchronuously returning the data as an array like so

```js
import { Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/forkJoin';

console.log("Owk ooo let's play small with observables ");

// this is just to form an asynchronous process
asyncSimulator(data: number): Observable < any > {
  return Observable.create(observer => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      observer.next("data to send can be object or anything" + data);
      console.log("am done");
      observer.complete(); //to show we are done with our processing 
    }, 2000);
  })
}

/** 
call the all asynchronous process here, like so with Fork Join
*/
Observable.forkJoin([
    this.asyncSimulator(1),
    this.asyncSimulator(2),
    this.asyncSimulator(3),
  ])
  .subscribe(results => {
    let async1 = result[0];
    let async2 = result[1];
    let async3 = result[1];
    console.log("results is an array", results);
  });
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hmm, sorry, I don't get it. How do I get another Observable after my subscribe() has finished? I could add a complete() handler. But I don't what to do in it ...

Comment: oh, am just emulating an asynchronous task with the `asyncSimulator` method, the main thing is the `forkJoin` see how it was called, you pass your different async process as an array and then the subscribe result is an array of the results in the order you pass your async processes @Knack